# How to create a widget or a frame for each list that I add in PyQt5?

Tags: python, for-loop, pyqt, pyqt5

Actually, I'm facing a problem that some of you guys may find simple, and to be honest I don't know why I can't solve it... I`m actually tried everything!

So first of all, here's my code:

```
class UpdateFrame(QtWidgets.QFrame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: white;'
                           'border: 0px solid #4f4f51;'
                           'border-radius: 0px;'
                           'margin: 0px;'
                           'padding: 0px;')

        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())

        for conteudo in range (20):
            self.layout().addWidget(ListFrame(update_list=["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"]))


class ListFrame(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, update_list):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet('.ListFrame{background-color: white;'
                                    'border: 1px solid #4f4f51;'
                                    'border-radius: 0px;'
                                    'margin: 2px;'
                                    'padding: 2px}')


        self.setMinimumSize(500, 150)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(_Secao(update_list, max_conteudo_exibido_int=5))

class _Secao(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__ (self, conteudo_list, titulo_stylesheet = 'QLabel {color: black; font-weight: bold}', max_conteudo_exibido_int = 100 ):
        super().__init__()

        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QGridLayout())

        _content_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        _content_frame.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        _content_frame.setFixedWidth(380)
        conteudo_a_ser_exibido = conteudo_list[:max_conteudo_exibido_int]

        if len(conteudo_list) == 0:
            _content_frame.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('--'))
            self.layout().addWidget(_content_frame)

        elif len(conteudo_list) > len(conteudo_a_ser_exibido):
            _content_frame.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('...'))
            self.layout().addWidget(_content_frame)

        else:
            conteudo_a_ser_exibido = conteudo_list[2: max_conteudo_exibido_int]

            _titulo_label_01 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Versão: ')
            _titulo_label_02 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Data: ')

            _titulo_label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(conteudo_list[0])
            _titulo_label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(conteudo_list[1])

            _titulo_label_01.setStyleSheet(titulo_stylesheet)
            _titulo_label_02.setStyleSheet(titulo_stylesheet)

            _titulo_label_1.setStyleSheet(titulo_stylesheet)
            _titulo_label_2.setStyleSheet(titulo_stylesheet)

            self.layout().addWidget(_titulo_label_01, 0, 0)
            self.layout().addWidget(_titulo_label_02, 0, 2)
            self.layout().addWidget(_titulo_label_1, 1, 0)
            self.layout().addWidget(_titulo_label_2, 1, 2)

            for conteudo in conteudo_a_ser_exibido:
                label_list = QtWidgets.QLabel(conteudo)
                label_list.setWordWrap(True)
                _content_frame.layout().addWidget(label_list)

                self.layout().addWidget(_content_frame, 2, 0)
            self.layout().addItem(QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding))
```

So, right now, this code create a window that shows the list `"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"` inside the frame created by `class ListFrame(QtWidgets.QFrame)`.

This list is called by `update_list`, that is received by `class UpdateFrame(QtWidgets.QFrame):`, inside the `for`, and it creates the same widget according to the `int` in `range` that I chose previously (in my example, 20 times);

So, here's what I'm trying to do: I need that this `for` function receives a list (instead of a number) that contain several lists inside of it and for each of those lists the GUI create a new widget that contains the content of those.

For example:

> [["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"], ["test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test10"]]

and with this, there will be 2 widget, each one with it own content.

I believe that my difficulty resides in the fact that I never worked with lists inside lists and doing so it's screwing with my brain.

Thank you all in anticipation for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your loop

```
for conteudo in range (20):
    self.layout().addWidget(ListFrame(update_list=["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"]))
```

replace with

```
for lst in list_of_lists:
    self.layout().addWidget(ListFrame(update_list=lst))
```

(where I gave the name `list_of_lists` for your

```
[["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"], ["test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test10"]]
```

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what I need!! Thank you so much!